# Website Returns Page Not Found when UTM Parameters appended

Tags: javascript, html, utm-tracking, azure-static-website-hosting

We have a website that currently returns a Page Not Found when UTM parameters are appended to it. This is across the homepage and all URL paths. Does not accept any strings that start with '?'. The standard, non-appended URLs work just fine.

Any insight into what might be causing this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you confirm that the HTTP Return code is 404? You can check that in your browser dev tools in the network tab.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy. I confirmed the Status is a 404. Type=Document, Initiator = Other

Comment: Did you configure any routes? If so, could you add them to your question, as there might be the cause for your error.

Comment: The string starting with `?` is called the query, the utm parameter is a query parameter. Probably the routes need to be configured in a way that any or certain query parameters still return the same resource.

Comment: That's great insight. I'm extremely raw in my web development skills and am using this as more of general insight to the issue so I can get our dev team pointed in the right direction, quick.

Comment: For my own benefit and insight, how would I look to see if any routes are configured?